# StreamReader - how to read line that contains certain string?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to find a line that contains a particular string, and print that entire line.

This is what i got so far:

```
using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
{
    string result;
    string recipe;                       
    while ((result = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (result.Contains("Recipe:"))
        {
            recipe = reader.ReadLine();                                                            
        }                            
    }                      
}
```

The problem is that this code will read the next line, and not the line that contains the string. How to read the line that contains the text "Recipe:"?

Comment: You already have it in `result`.  What's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the current `result` object instead, which already contains your current line :

```
if (result.Contains("Recipe:"))
{
        recipe = result;                                                           
}
```

The `reader.ReadLine()` call will always return the *next* line to be read, so when you call `result = reader.ReadLine()` that is actually setting the contents of `result` to your current line.

This explains why your result were incorrect when you were attempting to set your `recipe` inside your loop, as setting it to `reader.ReadLine()` would simply read the next line and use its result.

Comment: I would say you shouldn't even really store off an identical string, just use `result`.